# jquery mobile - URL being updated on preventdefault

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, popup

Have a problem that is driving me insane! I suspect I am doing something wrong...

I am using jQuery mobile with multiple pages in the same HTML file.

I have a page `#mainregister` on which I check for any user changes. If they try to navigate away, I stop the navigation using this code (using info I found here on SO):

```
    $(document).on("pageinit", '#mainregister', function(){
    $(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data){  
        ResetTimeOutTimer(); // Reset inactivity timer
        if (typeof data.toPage != "string") {
            if (isDirty) {

                var to = data.toPage.attr('id');
                to = '#' + to;
                console.log(to);
                if(to !== '#mainregister')
                {
                   var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                                + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    isDirty =  false;
                    console.log(to);
                    $("#leavebutton").on('click', function(){
                        changePage(to, false);
                        return false; // This is to prevent events bubbling up and causing double page flips
                                      // See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2369#issuecomment-4830800
                                        // and https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/
                    });

                    $("#leavetext").html(confirmationMessage);                  
                    $('#confirmLeave').popup('open'); 
                    return false;
                } 

            }
        }
    });

});
```

This brings up a popup asking the user if they wish to Save or Leave. This popup is defined as:

```
<!-- Leave Warning Popup -->
        <div data-role="popup" id="confirmLeave" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
                <h1>Info</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content" id="leaveContent">
                <h3 class="ui-title" id="leavetext"></h3>
                <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveRegister()"/>
                <input type="button" value="Leave" id="leavebutton"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Leave Warning Popup -->
```

Now, if the user goes 'back' from `#mainregister` the navigation is stopped and the popup is shown. If the user chooses save, the save occurs but the URL still changes even though we're still on `#mainregister' page.

So, user is on `index.html/#mainregister`, hits back button, popup comes up, user chooses to save, popup closes, page shown is still `#mainregister` but URL is now `index.html` but should be `index.html/#mainregister`.

So, now the URL and the actual page do not match; and navigation is a little broken from here.

Am I using the wrong page event? Or something else?

Also (perhaps related) I notice that if I go back after a popup (in other use cases) I get the same URL twice - e.g. `\index.html#\index.html (is this because I am testing from file:// or something else)?